# In AngularJS, after using jqLite .html() method the angular directives do not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the jqLite's `.html()` method to replace some content on my HTML page. I used

`angular.element(document).find('myElement').html(myContentFromServer');`

to replace some content. But, `myContentFromServer` has some directives, like `ng-model` in it. But, it doesn't seem to cause any effect.

Do I need to `$compile` or something..?

Please help out.

Comment: jsfiddle or plunker  link can help us to debug code here....

Comment: Yes, you need to use the `$compile` service if the added content has directives. Also instead of finding the element to add content, use an element directive to add and $compile the content

Comment: okay.. but $compiling is not possible outside a directive, right? @georgeawg

Comment: The `$compile` service needs a `$scope`. To `$compile` HTML with `ng-model` in it, the `ng-model` directive needs a `$scope`.